# How can I get the value of a session variable inside a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, static, session-variables

I am using ASP.NET page methods with jQuery.... How do I get the value of a session variable inside a static method in C#?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = "Pandiya";
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetName()
{
    string s = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    return s;
}
```

When I compile this I get the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'`

Comment: use HttpContext.Current like this:
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Session["..."]`

`HttpContext.Current` gets you the current ... well, Http Context; from which you can access: Session, Request, Response etc

Comment: HttpContext.Current gives you access to the current Http Context as explained in the edit i just did. The HttpContext.Current property is static (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext_members.aspx) and it does it's magic and returns you the current HttpContext. You should have access to most of the stuff you have access in the code behind etc.

Comment: P.S. You were trying to access a non-static property (Session property) via a static method... obviously it(the Session property) exists only on an instance of the class! Hope this explains things better?

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: `Session` is a instance property of the Page class that returns an `HttpSessionState` object.  When you write something like `Session["..."]`, this is really `this.Session["..."]`.  Because a static member has no `this` object, you can't access the `Session` property.  You can, however, access the same `HttpSessionState` object using the code that hwwishart suggested.

Comment: @jwwishart: Sorry for mistyping your name in the previous comment.  J and H are right next to each other and the room is dark at the moment.

Comment: How can we use the Page, Application etc in static method,

Comment: This is not working for me. I can get the HttpContext.Current.Session in debugger watch window, but it does not have the session variable that was made on another page. It has the same session id though. I am also using a static web method too - which is where I need it.

Answer (score 21):

If you haven't changed thread, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session`, as indicated by jwwishart.

`HttpContext.Current` returns the context associated with the thread. Obviously this means you can't use it if you've started a new thread, for example. You *may* also need to consider thread agility - ASP.NET requests don't always execute on the same thread for the whole of the request. I *believe* that the context is propagated appropriately, but it's something to bear in mind.

Comment: SessionState works with page methods and I believe your concerns are not valid Jon (other than if a new thread is started by our own code, I don't know what happens then). I'd be more nervous of your unqualified suggestion that "Ideally you should pass all the information you need from the client instead" as that very much depends on the nature of the data - I have seen some very [dangerous examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30683127/397817) in the wild! I'd rather say "it depends".

Comment: @StephenKennedy: I've removed the last paragraph entirely rather than spending ages adding nuance for a nearly-8-year-old answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current `Session` via [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) - a *static* property through which you can retrieve the `HttpContext` instance that applies to the current web request. This is a common pattern in static App Code and static page methods.

```
string s = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"];
```

The same technique is used to access the `Session` from within ASMX web methods decorated with `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` because whilst such methods are not static they do not inherit from `Page` and thus do not have direct access to a `Session` property.

Static code can access the [Application Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx) in the same way:

```
string var1 = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Var1"];
```

If the static code is inside another  project we need to reference `System.Web.dll`. However, in this case it is *generally* best to avoid such a dependency because if the code is called from outside of an ASP.NET context `HttpContext.Current` will be `null`, for obvious reasons. Instead, we can require a `HttpSessionState` as an argument (we'll still need the reference to `System.Web` of course):

```
public static class SomeLibraryClass
{
    public static string SomeLibraryFunction(HttpSessionState session)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Call:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetName()
{
    return SomeLibraryClass.SomeLibraryFunction(HttpContext.Current.Session);
}
```