# checking session variable (null or not) causes an Exception in a Handler class

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpcontext, ihttphandler

I have a situation like the one described in this thread:
[How can i get the value of a session variable inside a static method in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577183/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-session-variable-inside-a-static-method-in-c)

However, there are no static methods here (just a class inherited from IHttpHandler)

Here is my code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Telerik.Web.Examples.FileExplorer.FilterAndDownloadFiles.Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace Telerik.Web.Examples.FileExplorer.FilterAndDownloadFiles
{
    [RadCompressionSettings(HttpCompression = CompressionType.None)] // Disable RadCompression for this page ;
    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        private HttpContext _context;
        private HttpContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                return _context;
            }
            set
            {
                _context = value;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            string filePath = context.Request.QueryString["path"];
            filePath = context.Server.MapPath(filePath);

            if (filePath == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
            System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(streamReader.BaseStream);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[streamReader.BaseStream.Length];

            br.Read(bytes, 0, (int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length);

            if (bytes == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            streamReader.Close();
            br.Close();
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string MimeType = GetMimeType(fileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            char[] extension_ar = extension.ToCharArray();
            string extension_Without_dot = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i < extension_ar.Length; i++)
            {
                extension_Without_dot += extension_ar[i];
            }

            //if (extension == ".jpg")
            //{ // Handle *.jpg and
            //    WriteFile(bytes, fileName, "image/jpeg jpeg jpg jpe", context.Response);
            //}
            //else if (extension == ".gif")
            //{// Handle *.gif
            //    WriteFile(bytes, fileName, "image/gif gif", context.Response);
            //}
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"] != null)
        {
            WriteFile(bytes, fileName, MimeType + " " + extension_Without_dot,      context.Response);
        }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a byte array to the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="content">binary file content</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">the filename to be sent to the client</param>
        /// <param name="contentType">the file content type</param>
        private void WriteFile(byte[] content, string fileName, string contentType, HttpResponse response)
        {
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = contentType;

            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            response.BinaryWrite(content);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }

        private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
        {
            string mimeType = "application/unknown";
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
            if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
                mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            return mimeType;
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In the line of  `if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"] != null)` I get the following exception when session variable is null :

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're passing the context into the method. Have you tried using that context instead? Also, have you considered using a nullable parameter and passing the session value into the method from the calling method?

Comment: hi dear james / i have some javascript codes that use this handler / i want to check session value inside handler / but i had the upper error...

Comment: See the answer from @Matthew Abbott. That should take care of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because generic handlers are designed to be barebone request processors, they do not by default support Session. What you need to do, is decorate your handler class with the `IRequiresSessionState` interface:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

This causes the ASP.NET runtime to initialise the session container for the request. You can then use the `Session` instance from your `HttpContext`.

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. Does that interface implement any methods OP needs to be aware of?

Comment: @JamesJohnson - No, it is a marker interface only, the handler needs to just be decorated with the interface and the runtime takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Matthew Abbott thanks for answer / but couses another error -> Compiler Error Message: CS1722: Base class 'IRequireSessionState' must come before any interfaces

Comment: `IRequiresSessionState` is an interface, not a class. Can you update your question with your revised `Handler` class declaration?

Comment: @Matthew Abbott thanks for attention / but my entire class is in my Q ... i have some javascript codes that use Handler.ashx file inside my project / in this file (i pasted entire codes in my Q) i want to check my session variable!

Comment: I mean, update your question to include the change you've made to include `IRequiresSessionState`

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Comment: Don't post only a link as an aswer. At least write something, or post the link as a comment. Fix it and I'll upvote it.