# Why session in cs class file is null ? (web project .net 2010)

Tags: asp.net, class, session, session-variables, webproject

i have a cs class file in a web project in vs 2010.
in class,i read and wirte session variables.
but my Session property is null!

i use this:

```
 public static int UserID
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] == null) return 0;
                return int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = value;
            }

        }
```

**but my HttpContext.Current.Session is null(no HttpContext.Current.Session["x"])**

**note web project has no App_Code folder.**

how to use session in my class?

Answer (score 0):

Because your property is static and Sessions are not static.
So you can not access it.

For more informaton, see links below:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577183/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-session-variable-inside-a-static-method