# How can I use session variables in a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core. How can I use session variables in a static method?

In ASP.NET, this looked like this:

```
protected static string AssignSession()  
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = "super user";
}
```

When I try that in ASP.NET Core, I get the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, 
>   or property 'ControllerBase.HttpContext'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the value of a session variable inside a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577183/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-session-variable-inside-a-static-method)

Comment: Sir, i am asking Asp.net-core.

Comment: Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[...]`

Comment: First of all, why use a static method? Second, there's no static HttpContext instance in ASP.NET Core, nor a `Page_Load` event - there are no events at all. [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is now a property of the controller or PageModel. You'll have [to enable Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) before you can use it too.  If you want to access the Session object in another method you'll have to pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 4):

The answer is generally: You don’t.

In ASP.NET Core, you pretty much avoid static code. Instead, ASP.NET Core uses [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to make services available as dependencies and to control their lifetime.

A static utility class in ASP.NET would probably translate to a singleton service in ASP.NET Core. Using that is very straightforward; you start by creating a non-static service that does whatever you want to do. Since this is using dependency injection, you can just depend on other services as well:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SetSomeSessionValue(string value)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        httpContext.Session["example"] = value;
    }
}
```

You can do whatever you want there. The `IHttpContextAccessor` is used to retrieve the current HttpContext.

Then, you need to register your service with the dependency injection container. You do that in the `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyService>();

// we also add the HttpContextAccessor, in case it wasn’t already (implicitly) registered before
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And now, you can depend on this `MyService` within controllers or other services by simply adding it as a constructor argument:

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public HomeController(MyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _myService.SetSomeSessionValue("test");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, you have a non-static service that has clear dependencies and which you can test properly.

---

That all being said, many constructs already have access to the current `HttpContext` and as such to the session. For example, in controllers, Razor pages, or even Razor views, you can just access the `HttpContext` directly as it is an *instance* variable.

So if you are not building some reusable utility code, you don’t actually need to create a service for this. You could just for example create a (non-static) utility method within your controller that then accesses the `HttpContext` directly.